# C# Button Background Color

Tags: c#, button, components, styles

i have a Windows Form, and i want make a modern design.
I'm just having a problem with button styling, you can help-me?

I want to remove or hide the background color when the button was clicked, I managed to remove the background color from when the mouse is over the component with the following code:

```
FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

Now i need remove or hide this (grey background):
[Form Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv6zi.png)

How i make this?

Thank you!

Comment: Show what you did. It seems you are clearing too much background (if it's winforms).

Comment: Hi @Sinatr, i have a extension of Button, see this: [link](https://prnt.sc/saqr5u) and here [link](https://prnt.sc/saqruk) I have an event that makes a personalization like hovering, printing the border and some other things...
Note: the gray background appears when I click the button, and I want to remove it, I already made a function for when I click, the button becomes a little darker, so the gray background is unnecessary and unpleasant.

Comment: Please include the code in your using code brackets.

Comment: @Coding-Is-An-Adventure I have a class that extends the Button object with more than 100 lines, I cannot put all the code here, there is a character limit, forgive me.

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Note: this is because I decided to leave the edges of the button round, to leave it in the style that my application will be, if you use the square button, the rectangle hides this gray background, but as I rounded it became visible.

Comment: `g.FillEllipse(brush, _borderThicknessByTwo, _borderThicknessByTwo, Height - _borderThickness,
                Height - _borderThickness);
            g.FillEllipse(brush, (Width - Height) + _borderThicknessByTwo, _borderThicknessByTwo,
                Height - _borderThickness, Height - _borderThickness);
            g.FillRectangle(brush, Height / 2 + _borderThicknessByTwo, _borderThicknessByTwo,
                Width - Height - _borderThickness, Height - _borderThickness);`

Comment: round buttons will have rather rough edges. Winforms in not good at glitz. step one is to go for a flatstyle button.

Comment: Because of this part of the code this occurs.
Let me explain.
This section makes a square in the center of the button and puts two circles in the corners, to make the button with rounded edges, as I removed all stylization of the button to do this, the gray background started to appear, even if I did not remove the style of the Button completely, this gray background appears.

Comment: @TaW the buttons are with rough edges yes, but a code that activates a kind of anti-aliasing, `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;`

Comment: This will only work for stuff you draw. It will not work if you need to clip a Region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtained the solution with many attempts.
Just change the FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor and FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor to the background color of the Form or the item it is attached to.

Example: You have a form with a panel, the color of the panel is red, so set the attributes to red, or just put "Color.Transparent"

```
buttonName.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArg(255, 0, 0) // red;
buttonName.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent; // same result
```

So, if you have a class that extends the Button object, just make code like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
        public MyButton()
        {
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent; // or Color.[Preference]
            FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent; // or Color.[Preference]
        }

        // Rest of your code...
}
```

Otherwise, do a foreach, as below

```
foreach (var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
         button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent; // or Color.[Preference]
         button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent; // or Color.[Preference]
}
```

The codes above are examples for everyone to be able to build their own logic, if in doubt I can help you.